# Can you configure Rails to precompile ALL files under a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

Yes, there are a million questions asking how to register a directory for the assets pipeline. But my question is slightly different...

I'm building a basic theme system and the file structure will look like this:

```
app/assets/skins/
             some_theme/
                 style.css.scss
                 fonts/
                    font1.woff
                    font2.woff
                 images/
                     whocares.png
             another_theme/
                 ...
```

As you can see, the theme-specific assets are bundled in their own directories. When I new theme gets added, I don't want it to require any tinkering with the configurations.

**Can I configure the asset pipeline to search/precompile ALL the files under `app/assets/skins/`?**

I think I want something like this in application.rb...

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'skins', '**')
```

...but this isn't how it works. How does it work?

Answer (score 2):

To include all your scripts: add to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require_tree ../skins
```

To include all your styles: add to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
*= require_tree ../skins
```

Or the equivalent syntax for sass (better than using comments):

```
@import '../skins/**/*'
```

To include all other assets add to `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Dir.glob( Rails.root.join( 'app', 'assets', 'skins', '**' ) ).each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

And to access for example `app/assets/skins/a_theme/skin.png` you can use view helpers like:

```
<%= image_tag 'skin.png' %>
```

And in your sass files helpers like:

```
background-image: image-url('skin.png')
```

The same for fonts assets.

UPDATE: just to clear a point: with `Dir.glob` if 2 images have the same name in different paths only the first in paths list will be used

Comment: Thanks Mat! I think you've solved my problem but I wanted to clarify one thing. I _don't_ want to bundle all my theme files into the main js / css file. I want to maintain a global stylesheet. And then separately include the active theme's stylesheet. Does that make sense? Can I just skip the first bit about  `require_tree` etc? Or does that detail change your answer?

Comment: @emersonthis: so... you would like to create the main application.css / js and another theme.css / js for your theme...? This changes a lot. I suppose that Rails pipeline could create only a single file .css / .js as output - you could use a build system like Gulp or Grunt but it could be a bit tricky. Or you could create an empty Rails project only with your theme to generate the application.css / js, then move that files into another app (in assets) - not a great solution, but should work BUT remember that fonts / images are not bundled, only copied in /public/assets (with a digest hash)

Comment: Right. The reason I want to keep the theme files out of the main css file is that the there will be a lot of themes and they need to be switched on the fly. So it will get messy if there is one gigantic css file with all the themes rolled in. I'm agnostic about the location of the themes. The only reason I placed them in the app/assets/ was to try to be compliant with the preferred Rails convention. But they can go elsewhere if that makes things easier. All I really need the pipeline for is to compile the scss theme file and make images etc available from the view files.

Comment: Another option could be to put your theme folder in an ENV var or in a YAML file (ex. `current_theme = "app/assets/skins/a_theme"`). You add it with `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << current_theme`. The assets will be bundled in a unique file but it will be easier to switch theme editing the YAML or ENV

Comment: I think I'm still not explaining the situation clearly. I need ALL the themes to be compiled because the user will be able to activate/deactivate them dynamically. Can the yaml file do multiple themes? If so that could work. Maybe elaborate on that in a new answer? I didn't see any documentation on that

Comment: This is getting complicated @emersonthis :) And different users could select different themes? A way that work only for styles is to change a class on the body of the layout based on a user trait (a cookie/session, a field from DB, etc.) - ex. (ERB) `<body class="<%= @user_theme %>">` - then your styles should be like (SCSS): `my_theme1 { a { color: red; } }` (you could even put all in a unique file)

Comment: Correct. Different users, different themes etc. I considered the approach you described (globbing all themes together) but there are expected to be a lot, so I'd rather not keep growing the stylesheet bigger and bigger if possible.

Comment: I thought it over and I think I _can_ get away with bundling all the themes into one file by keeping theme very small. However the note about each file name needing to be unique is a problem. I could easily see two theme authors naming their stylesheet "style.scss". Can you think of an elegant way around this?

Comment: The note I wrote is about images / fonts only. Styles and scripts are merged so you shouldn't have problems here

Comment: Right ok but same problem with images. I don't have a way to ensure uniqueness